# In how many ways can you solve the following diophantine?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I need to find the number of solutions to this diophantine:

$$x_1 + x_2+x_3 +...+x_9=42$$

where $0\le x_n \le9 $ for $1\le n \le9 $.

I immediately thought about this as an 'urns and balls' question, where I try to put 42 balls into 9 distinguishable urns. However, I cannot seem to determine how to establish a way limit the number of balls in each urn to 9. Any ideas?

Comment: This may be of help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTCScjoPymA

Comment: I had a look at the video and it's good but doesn't look at conditions. So in the example of the video, he doesn't look at how to make sure there are no more than 6 onion bagels, say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), the number of non-negative solutions of
$$x_1 + x_2+x_3 +...+x_9=42$$
is $\binom{42+8}{8}$.

In order to impose the condition $x_n\leq 9$ use the [Inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Call $A_i$ the number of non-negative solutions such that $x_i\geq 10$. Then, again by stars-and-bars,
$$|A_i|=\binom{42-10+8}{8}$$
What about $|A_i\cap A_j|$ with $i\not=j$?

Note that by Inclusion-exclusion principle the number that you are looking for is
$$\binom{42+8}{8}-\sum_{1\leq i\leq 9} |A_i|+\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq 9} |A_i\cap A_j|-\sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq 9} |A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k|\\
+\sum_{1\leq i<j<k<l\leq 9} |A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k\cap A_l|.$$
Can you take it from here and fill the gaps?

P.S. Finally the result you should obtain is
$$\sum_{k=0}^4(-1)^k\binom{9}{k}\binom{42-10k+8}{8}=44865975.$$

Answer (score 3):

One solution is that you are looking for the coefficient of $x^{42}$ in $(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^9)^9=\left(\frac {x^{10}-1}{x-1}\right)^9$ and ask [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Power%20series%20((x%5E10-1)%2F(x-1))%5E9) for help.  Stopping the inner sum at $x=9$ imposes the maximum condition you are after.  After several pushes of the more terms button it gives $44865975$.

Comment: @RobertZ:  you are correct, I had a typo in the input.  Fixed.  Thanks